# Tikz - Flow Diagram with Shading and Group Highlighting

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, workflow

I've tried to create a tikz flow diagram with specific parts of the steps grouped and highligted with a shadow behind. Please see the following powerpoint sketch that illustrates the desired looking.

[image]

Can you guys provide guidance? Any tips/hints that help achieving the shadowing and the cutting line between "Text 1" and "Text 2"?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For shadow you can use `fit` library and draw nodes in image background. For white block define common style with white fill. However, search on site or on https://texample.net/ for similar diagrams and use the most similar for base for your diagram.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work, tried the code from https://texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/ but without any success. Even the arrow back does not work properly, the same is true for the shadowing when using the fit library for framing the nodes and labels inside. Would you mind to include a minimal working example of your idea, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

OK, as starting point:

**Edit:**
let me add one more group of nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=3.1241592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 4mm,
   box/.style = {draw, fill=white, font=\sffamily,
                 minimum width=12mm, minimum height=6mm},
   FIT/.style = {draw, fill=gray!30,
                 inner xsep=4mm, inner ysep=3mm,
                 fit=#1},
every edge/.style = {draw,-{Triangle[scale=0.8]}}
                       ]
%% group 3
\node(n31) [box] {3.1};
\node(n30) [box, above=of n31] {4.2};
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f3)  [FIT=(n30) (n31)] {};
%% group 4
\node(n41) [box, right=12mm of n31] {4.1}; % <---
\node(n42) [box, right=of n41] {4.2};
\node(n43) [box, right=of n42] {4.3};
%
\node(n40) [box, above=of n42] {4.3};
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f4)  [FIT=(n40) (n41) (n43)] {};
%%%% arrows
\draw   (n30) edge (n40)
% 
        (n41) edge (n42)
        (n42) edge (n43);
% dashed line
\coordinate[ left=of f3] (aux1);
\coordinate[right=of f4] (aux2);
\draw[densely dashed, thick]    (aux1) -- (aux2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the starting point! This let me expierment a bit, however, still facing some issues. Please see the other answer I posted below for details.

Comment: Hey there, sorry, this does not work for me after c&p. The box to the left does not show up, rather becomes merged with the other "bigger" box to the right. Thus, I am getting a picture with 4.2 connected to 4.3 to be in the same background box. Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: I do not know, what you doing. I show you, hoe to draw two block from your image. On the same way you need to add the first (draw before second one) and last block, connect nodes in in the top line in them by arrows and add node 1 above node 2. This should not be so difficult. Do you expect, that I should draw complete image instead of you?

Comment: No, certainly not. It's simply that the picture you posted is not being produced by the code you uploaded. If you check your updated code snippet with what I posted prior to your suggestions (I guess the answer is hidden now, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634236/flow-diagram-with-fit-library-and-tikz), you recognize that I already did the same without success.

Comment: In group 4, replace `\node(n41) [box] {4.1};` by `\node(n41) [right = 15mm of n31, box] {4.1};` and that's fine.